# Mongoose populate method only storing one Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to access the array of Message Models that is stored in my Conversation Model. However, when I use the populate method to try to store the Message models as an array, only the first Message is showing up.

```
socket.on('connected', function (data) {
      //load all messages
      const filter = { roomId: data.roomid };
      (async () => {
        console.log('searching for Schema');
        let conversation = await Conversation.findOne(filter)
          .populate('messages')
          .exec(function (err, message) {
            if (err) console.log('no schema found');
            var array = message.messages;
            console.log(array);
            // printing only first Message
          });
      })();
    });
```

Conversation Schema

```
const ConversationSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        roomId: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        messages: {
            type:  mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Message' 
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
);
```

Comment: are you trying to store like update the messages or retrieve the messages?

Comment: I am trying to retrieve the messages

Comment: update your messages field to `messages: [{type:  mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Message'  }]` and sure that you have data in this field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

populate method not store message as an array.Population is the process of automatically replacing the specified paths in the document with document(s) from other collection(s).[Refer this for more detail](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#:%7E:text=Mongoose%20has%20a%20more%20powerful,from%20other%20collection(s).)

To solve your problem modify declaration of messages field in Conversation Schema

```
messages: [{
            type:  mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Message' 
        }]
```